# Angular2: Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: angular

I've have something like :

account.component.ts

```
getCoworker(id:number){
  this.userService.getCoworker(id)
    .subscribe(
      worker => this.worker = worker
   )
}

onViewCoworker(id){
  this.getCoworker(id);
}
```

account.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="viewCoworkers" class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <ul class="collection">
        <a (click)="onViewCoworker(coworker.id)" *ngFor="let coworker of coworkers" class="collection-item avatar valign-wrapper" id="coworker{{coworker.id}}">
          <span class="title">{{coworker.name}} {{coworker.surname}}</span>
          <p>{{coworker.job}}</p>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div *ngIf="viewCoworker" class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12 center-align">
  <div class="card center-align">
      <div class="card-title">{{worker.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

user.service.ts

```
getCoworker(id:number):Observable<User[]>{
  const token = this.authService.getToken();
  let url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/coworker/' + id + '?token=';
  return this.http.get(url+token)
    .map(res=> res.json())
    .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

json response

```
[{"id":25,"name":"lulu","surname":"lu","email":"test@test.com","phone":"0606060606","number":1102,"street":"rue de ketazi","zip":"31200","city":"London","job":"developpeur web","skills":null,"project":"ketaz party","avatarPath":null,"birthDate":null,"inscriptionDate":null,"status":null,"disabledDate":"1970-01-01","role":null,"password":"$2y$10$zyCtW4U73TPy8orLO58yieorKS\/4DezqL.P6VZs66LSYyHuzC9YJK","fidelityPoint":12,"remember_token":null,"created_at":"2017-08-21 19:05:44","updated_at":"2017-08-24 12:59:56"}]
```

getCoworker in user.servie works fine (return json in postman)
But when i call onViewCoworker(coworker.id) in template, console print :

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./AccountComponent class AccountComponent - inline template:154:34 caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I've tried {{worker?.name}} : no more error, but no data displaying.

Somehow it doesnt return "worker".
I guess i'm missing something ?

Comment: can you post the json response from userService.getCoworker

Comment: @LLai post edited

Comment: It looks like the json is being returned in an array. So to display {{worker.name}} you need to access the first object of the array. .subscribe(worker => this.worker = worker[0])

Comment: LLai thx for answering, but i still got the same error

Comment: hmm can you post more of your component code? Is there another api that populates your coworkers property, which in turn populates the ngFor in account.component.html? If so do you need to call your service to get the coworkers data? It seems like that data is available in your ngFor. So you could potentially pass the coworker data through onViewCoworker() and assign it to this.worker, avoiding the userService.getCoworker altogether

Comment: @LLai you're right, coworkers data are available in ngFor, so i could use it and avoiding calling userService.getCoworker. I'll try that thanks. (but still doesnt explain the actual error :) )

Comment: {{worker[0].name}} in template did the trick ... thanks @LLai

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `user.service.ts`

```js
getCoworker(id: number): Observable < User > {
  const token = this.authService.getToken();
  let options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();
  let headers: Headers = new Headers();
  //headers.append("key", value);
  options.headers = headers;

  options.params = new URLSearchParams();
  options.params.append("token", token);

  let url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/coworker/' + id;
  return this.http.get(url, options)
    .map((res: any) => res.json() as User)
    .catch(err: Response) => Observable.throw(this.handleError /* or method that can use the content of the err variable. 404 page perhaps */ ));
}
```

If you're only expecting a single user object from that request, you don't need return type to be an array.

It may have thrown that because your `.map()` was not mapping the Json to any thing. It's essentially sending a Json object to the `Subscribe()` method. So, in theory, you were trying to read `.name` from a Json.